# Go : Why do ANSI exscape codes not work when using the buffer to print to std.out?

Tags: go, cmd, command-line

So I am trying to get items to print to the command line and I want to do it quickly, so I am using this method to print to cmd as it is quicker than fmt.print :

```
buf := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
fmt.Fprint(buf, "text here")
```

I have run several tests and this is the quickest method of printing to the screen. But there is an issue, I also want to print ansi escape codes to move the cursor around, change colours etc.

This piece of code works, what it should do is move the cursor position to 0,0 and it  does

```
fmt.Printf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0)
```

However when I try to use the buffer to achieve the same it does nothing

```
start := fmt.Sprintf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0)
buf := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
fmt.Fprint(buf, start)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to achieve this using the buffer? Many thanks

This was done on windows 11 using cmd, not powershell

Comment: Use of `bufio` won't affect the escape sequences, but if you forget to *flush* the buffer before returning, use of `bufio` can *suppress the output entirely*. I suspect you forgot a `defer buf.Flush()`. (Note that it's a good idea to check for an error from `Flush`, but that's a little harder in a `defer`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was printing out 1 row too many and this was causing data to not be overwritten when returning to 0,0, I get the impression that x, y is relative to the view port so data was scrolling off screen.

The different behaviour was indeed caused by not flushing the buffer. So including a flush in the for loop where I was printing to the screen fixed that.